# Using JPA, in JSP, can't retrieve property of @ManyToOne mapped entity

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jpa, jstl

Using JPA, MVC-JSP+Servlets, JSTL

Entities and significant properties:

Entity `Post`:

```
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name = "post_title", length=300, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "post_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "post_content", length=50000, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "post_visitors", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer visitors;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { ALL }, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "post")
    @OrderBy("date DESC")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();
...
}
```

Entity `User`:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name = "user_name", length=45, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String name;    

    @Column(name = "user_username", length=45, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "user_password", length=45, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { ALL }, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<Post>();
...
}
```

Servlets doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Post post = null;
    int postId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("postId"));
    post = postDao.findById(postId);

    // increase post "visitors" number
    int visitors = post.getVisitors();
    visitors ++;
    post.setVisitors(visitors);
    post = postDao.merge(post);

    System.out.println("User id: " + post.getUser().getId());
    System.out.println("User name: " + post.getUser().getName());

    request.setAttribute("post", post);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("post.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

JSP (post.jsp) part:

```
<section>
   <header>${post.title}</header>
      <div>
    Posted by <strong>${post.user.name}</strong> on: 
               <fmt:formatDate value="${post.date}" type="date" />
           comments(${fn:length(post.comments)}) views(${post.visitors})
      </div>
      <article>
        <p>${post.content}</p>
      </article>
</section>
```

Now, problem I have is that I am not getting value of `${post.user.name}` in jsp. All other `post` details in jsp are there but not `${post.user.name}`. What could be reason for this?

EDIT:
bean `merge` method:

```
public T merge(T entity) {
    entity = em.merge(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: The user might be null. The user name might be null. The user name might be an empty or blank string. Check its value in the controller.

Comment: @JBNizet You are wright. User name is `null`. But user id IS there. See my updated servlets doGet method content. I am getting `User Id: 4` and `User name: null`. And user's name is not `null` in database. I am not sure am I using `post = postDao.merge(post);` properly. Can you see if code in servlets doGet method is correct?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet I am definitely not setting and updating post `visitors` field properly. I have commented that part of code and now I am getting user details (but without `visitors` property updated).

Comment: @JBNizet Not sure exactly why, but removing `post =` from `post = postDao.merge(post);` gives proper `post` object. (you can see entity `merge` in question update) If you know the reason for this, post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Data Access Objects in application (`xxxDAOBean`) extend `GenericDAOBean`, and merging method in `GenericDAOBean` is:

```
public T merge(T entity) {
    entity = em.merge(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

where `T` is type of an entity. So, for `post` object (entity type `Post`), merging should be used with `postDao.merge(post);`